# Return all from table but only where distinct field is greater than 1

Tags: t-sql, distinct

SQL 2008

Basically i have a dataset that looks like this:

```
AcctID  AcctType  AcctSubType  Curr  TransType  Amount  Sequence 
1        CCY       SET          EUR   Opening    1000   B
1        CCY       SET          EUR   BUY        -100   T
1        CCY       SET          EUR   SEL        100    T
1        CCY       SET          EUR   Closing    1000   B
2        CCY       SET          EUR   Opening    2000   B
2        CCY       SET          EUR   SEL        100    T
2        CCY       SET          EUR   Closing    2100   B
3        CCY       INC          EUR   Opening    1000   B
3        CCY       INC          EUR   SEL        200    T
3        CCY       INC          EUR   BUY        -100   T
3        CCY       INC          EUR   Closing    1100   B
4        CCY       SET          GBP   Opening    2000   B
4        CCY       SET          GBP   SEL        100    T
4        CCY       SET          GBP   Closing    2100   B
```

What i want to do is return all from the dataset where there are more than one capital account per currency (so basically more than one distinct AcctID).  A capital account is identified by AcctType = 'CCY' and AcctSubType = 'SET'.  Also i only want the balances, so where Sequence = 'B'.

So for the above dataset what would be returned is the following:

```
AcctID  AcctType  AcctSubType  Curr  TransType  Amount  Sequence 
1        CCY       SET          EUR   Opening    1000   B
1        CCY       SET          EUR   Closing    1000   B
2        CCY       SET          EUR   Opening    2000   B
2        CCY       SET          EUR   Closing    2100   B
```

I started off like this, but got confused how to include the distinct count of AcctID within a currency is greater than 1:

```
;;with test (AcctID, AcctType, AcctSubType, Curr, TransType, Amount, Sequence)
as 
( 
select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Opening', 1000, 'B'
union all select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'BUY', -100, 'T'
union all select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'SEL', 100, 'T' 
union all select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Closing', 1000, 'B' 
union all select 2, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Opening', 2000, 'B' 
union all select 2, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'SEL', 100, 'T'
union all select 2, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Closing', 2100, 'B' 
union all select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'Opening', 1000, 'B'
union all select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'SEL', 200, 'T' 
union all select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'BUY', -100, 'T' 
union all select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'Closing', 1100, 'B'
union all select 4, 'CCY', 'SET', 'GBP', 'Opening', 2000, 'B' 
union all select 4, 'CCY', 'SET', 'GBP', 'SEL', 100, 'T' 
union all select 4, 'CCY', 'SET', 'GBP', 'Closing', 2100, 'B' 
)
select *
from test t
where t.AcctType = 'CCY'
and t.AcctSubType = 'SET'
and t.Sequence = 'B'
and t.Curr in (select w.Curr
from test w
where w.AcctType = 'CCY'
and w.AcctSubType = 'SET'
and w.Sequence = 'B'
group by w.Curr
having COUNT(distinct w.AcctID) > 1)
```

Now this works for the dataset, although what concerned me is would this work if there was more than one currency with more than one capital account?  Does the code i've created work for what i want to achieve.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

**UPD.** And yes, your updated code seems to be working,

```
;with test (AcctID, AcctType, AcctSubType, Curr, TransType, Amount, Sequence) 
as  
(  
    select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Opening', 1000, 'B' 
    union all select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'BUY', -100, 'T' 
    union all select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'SEL', 100, 'T'  
    union all select 1, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Closing', 1000, 'B'  
    union all select 2, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Opening', 2000, 'B'  
    union all select 2, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'SEL', 100, 'T' 
    union all select 2, 'CCY', 'SET', 'EUR', 'Closing', 2100, 'B'  
    union all select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'Opening', 1000, 'B' 
    union all select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'SEL', 200, 'T'  
    union all select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'BUY', -100, 'T'  
    union all select 3, 'CCY', 'INC', 'EUR', 'Closing', 1100, 'B' 
    union all select 4, 'CCY', 'SET', 'GBP', 'Opening', 2000, 'B'  
    union all select 4, 'CCY', 'SET', 'GBP', 'SEL', 100, 'T'  
    union all select 4, 'CCY', 'SET', 'GBP', 'Closing', 2100, 'B'  
) ,
cte_2 AS (
    select AcctType, AcctSubType, Curr

    from test t 
    where 
        t.AcctType = 'CCY' 
        and t.AcctSubType = 'SET' 

    GROUP BY AcctType, AcctSubType, Curr
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT AcctID) > 1
)
SELECT test.* 
FROM test
INNER JOIN cte_2
    ON test.AcctType = cte_2.AcctType AND test.AcctSubType = cte_2.AcctSubType AND test.Curr = cte_2.Curr
WHERE test.Sequence = 'B'
```

Comment: That seems to work fine, how does that differ from my code?  which would be the better to use in your opinion, considering there could be many currencies with multiple capital accounts?

Comment: They're plenty similar, I wrote my one before you did your update. But my one looks more flexible, for example, in case if you need distinct pair Account + Customer you can not solve it with IN clause. But if there are no another conditions except you listed, you can use any of them.

Comment: Thanks for that, much appreciated for the help